# How to load a class without referring to it?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, classloader

I am using Java 6.

I have static block in one of my class say "MyStaticBlockClass.java".

There are no references to that class (MyStaticBlockClass.java) from the rest of my project.

Here I need to execute the static block in the above specified class at the time of JVM start up.

Is there a way to load the class into JVM without references to that class ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `Class.forName("your.pkg.MyStaticBlockClass")`. That was how JDBC used to work - the static initializer in the driver class would register itself as being capable of handling specific URLs.

Now, that mechanism was superceded by [`DriverManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html) discovering drivers in all kinds of other ways. You should *consider* whether some of those techniques would be appropriate in your situation too - in general, relying on a static initializer having executed feels like a code smell. It *may* not be, but it's worth at least thinking about alternative designs.